# GROUP BY clause is not working when retrieving data from access table

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

This is the query which we need to run:

```
$dbname = 'demo';
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
$result = $db->query('SELECT Table1.id,Table2.name,Table2.email,Table3.desc,Table1.ORDNUM,Table4.cust,Table4.Startdate,Table4.CNCLDATE,Table4.ship,Table1.qty,Table5.t5_NAME,Table5.t5_EMAIL,Table6.t6_NAME FROM (((((Table1 INNER JOIN Table4 on Table1.ORDNUM = Table4.ORDNUM)INNER JOIN Table2 on icust.CODE = Table4.CODE)inner join Table3 on Table4.TRMCODE = Table3.TRMCODE)inner join Table5 on Table5.t5_CODE = Table4.code)inner join Table6 on Table6.ID = Table4.div)' GROUP BY Table1.id);
```

There are many records available with Table1.id, so I need to group it by Table1.id. But it couldn’t be done. This is the error message I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Page.php on line ***

How can this be resolved?

Comment: your `GROUP BY Table1.id` is outside/after your quotes - `$result = $db->query('SELECT ...[rest of your query]...' GROUP BY Table1.id);`. Is that a copy/paste error here, or is that your actual code?

Comment: Nope, this is the query structure.. How can i modify to be correct? Help me

Answer (score 0):

You have a single-quote before the GROUP BY clause that's likely causing the error. Try moving it just before the final, end parenthesis.

```
$dbname = 'demo';
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
$result = $db->query('SELECT Table1.id,Table2.name,Table2.email,Table3.desc,Table1.ORDNUM,Table4.cust,Table4.Startdate,Table4.CNCLDATE,Table4.ship,Table1.qty,Table5.t5_NAME,Table5.t5_EMAIL,Table6.t6_NAME FROM (((((Table1 INNER JOIN Table4 on Table1.ORDNUM = Table4.ORDNUM)INNER JOIN Table2 on icust.CODE = Table4.CODE)inner join Table3 on Table4.TRMCODE = Table3.TRMCODE)inner join Table5 on Table5.t5_CODE = Table4.code)inner join Table6 on Table6.ID = Table4.div) GROUP BY Table1.id');
```

Comment: Fatal Error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object, this is the error showing for me